# ImportError: cannot import name 'field_validator' from 'pydantic'

Tags: python, pydantic

I am getting error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'field_validator' from 'pydantic'`  while writing a custom validator on fields of my model class generated from a schema.
Here is how I am importing:

```
from pydantic import field_validator
```

Verions being used:
pydantic version: `pypi:pydantic:1.10.7`
datamodel-code-generator: `pypi:datamodel-code-generator:0.17.1`

Please help me in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#:%7E:text=from%20pydantic.functional_validators%20import%20field_validator)

You want to

```py
from pydantic.functional_validators import field_validator
```

### Note:

Not available on 1.10 (or at least not mentioned in the official docs)

Comment: Didn't help. This gives error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic.functional_validators'`

Comment: Which version of the pydantic is above valid for?

Comment: latest, the official docs for 1.10 contain no mention of `field_validator` where did you get this code? Are you following some tutorial? Why not update?

Comment: Consider updating because it doesn't look like they'll keep maintaining v1 forever, seems like [1.10.x versions are just bugfixes](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic#pydantic-v110-vs-v2)

Comment: Yep. that was the issue. Needed to move to a 2.0.3 version to be able to use field_validators. The import which works for me is: `from pydantic import field_validator` 
https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/validators/#field-checks